# 304 Not Modified When If-None-Match is valid

Tags: node.js, caching, express, etag, postman

I am optimizing an Express JSON API for consumption by iOS & Android Apps and do not seem to be able to get Express to respond with the correct 304 header when the Apps specify an etag within the If-None-Match header.

I needn't setup Etag generation as Express was already providing those; however when the Apps specify that etag again in a second request; Express' response is still a 200 with the data, as you can see in my tests in Postman:

[image: Postman request with correct If-None-Match header and 200 response]

How can I enable this functionality?

**Update:** The iOS dev is seeing the correct 304 Not Modified responses from the Express server but I don't understand why I am not seeing them within Postman - Does Postman support such actions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just stumble across this today, you need to disable Postman default behaviour of sending `Cache-Control` as `none`. To do this just go to settings change **Send no-cache header** to **No**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Orlando that's "fixed" it :) Maybe they should throw a warning when they notice a cache header?

Comment: @Illizian Yeah right?, took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: also make sure to send the ETag just like postman returns it, in this case include the `""`