# How to use Etag with sailsjs

Tags: express, sails.js, etag, postman, http-status-code-304

I'm trying to improve the cache capabilities on my sails application.

Sails generate a Etag with its response but when I try to do a GET request with a header **'if-None-Match'** containing the Etag from the previous answer I can't get a **304 not Modified** response from the server (the response is indeed not Modified and the Etag I receive is the same as the previous one).

I'm using POSTMAN to test the server responses.

Is there a way for a sails server to send such status code on unmodified responses ? I can't find any resource for Etag usage in sails doc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sails.js is based on Express.js and the ETags are generated by Express.js. And according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542959/how-does-a-etag-work-in-expressjs), weak ETags are generated using CRC32 (source), strong ETags are generated using MD5 (source).

I use [DHC - REST/HTTP API Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) with **If-None-Match** header, it works perfect (return 304 Not Modified).

And I found that's because POSTMAN send NO-CACHE header to the server for testing purpose

```
'cache-control': 'no-cache',
```

You can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24561360/471840) and turn off this feature then everything will be fine.